# Pandas doesn't remove separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataset -> data.txt:

```
4         x                  x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
6         y                  y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7
9         z                  z1, z2
```

That's my code to import this data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data/xyz.txt', sep=',', names=range(20), delim_whitespace=True)
df.dropna(axis=1, how='all', inplace=True)
```

It looks nice but there is problem with 'comma'.

```
df.head()

    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   4   x   x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8
1   6   y   y1, y2, y3, y4, y5, y6, y7  NaN
2   9   z   z1, z2  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

My goal is remove all commas from all values. 
I can't do it from hand this is big data.
I don't want do it by nested loop over every value.

Comment: You use `delim_whitespace=True`, so your delimiter is white-space. Why are there mixed-delimiters in your file? This is a rather unweildy format, can you fix whatever is generating this to use a *regular* csv?

Comment: I can not fix it, but I can set delim_whitespace=False and then split first row. I hope there is another option for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `replace` form dataframe

```
df.replace({',':''},regex=True)
Out[1280]: 
   0  1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  4  x  x1  x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8
1  6  y  y1  y2   y3   y4   y5   y6   y7  NaN
2  9  z  z1  z2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a hacky fix: subset the columns that are problematic, then use `.apply` and apply the `pd.Series` method `.str.replace`:

```
In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   0  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  4  x  x1,  x2,  x3,  x4,  x5,  x6,  x7,   x8
1  6  y  y1,  y2,  y3,  y4,  y5,  y6,   y7  NaN
2  9  z  z1,   z2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

In [18]: df.loc[:,range(2, 10)].apply(lambda S: S.str.replace(',',''))
Out[18]:
    2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  x1  x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8
1  y1  y2   y3   y4   y5   y6   y7  NaN
2  z1  z2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

So, just do this with `loc`-based assignment:

```
In [19]: df.loc[:, range(2, 10)] = df.loc[:,range(2, 10)].apply(lambda S: S.str.replace(',',''))

In [20]: df
Out[20]:
   0  1   2   3    4    5    6    7    8    9
0  4  x  x1  x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8
1  6  y  y1  y2   y3   y4   y5   y6   y7  NaN
2  9  z  z1  z2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```